# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for String.split()

Tags: java, arrays, split

This is the code for reading input from a file which contains student details in the form `roll,name,age,street,city,zipcode`.
Few values among these can be `null` even.

For the following code,  I am getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

Code is as follows-

```
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){

        split_array=line.split("\\,");

        String roll1=split_array[0];
        String name=split_array[1];// This is the line which causes Exception
        String age1=split_array[2];
        String street=split_array[3];
        String city=split_array[4];
        String zip=split_array[5];
    }
```

Comment: why are you splitting by `\,` instead of by `,` ?

Comment: Show me the content for your `fileName`

Comment: Are you sure that all lines you're reading have at least 5 commas? You may find an extra blank line at the end of the file that could be the cause of this exception.

Comment: you don't need ``\\,`` you can just do with `,`

Comment: The content of the fileName is this way-                                            line1-  4,Neha,10,Camp,Pune,411023
line2-    5,Seema,,,,                                                                              line3-  8,Neha,,,Mumbai, 
line4-  9,Meena,9,Nariman Point,Mumbai,411045
line5-  10,Chaitali,3,M.G.Road,Mumbai,411032

Comment: As pointed out rgettman, is there an empty line in the file (for instance, the last line)? This would result in an array of length 1, and exception when you try and access value at index 1.

Comment: Yes, there are few empty lines.. But, I have included while loop to check if the file's line is null

Comment: The empty lines are the problem. You should check `split_array.length` before accessing it.

Comment: `But, I have included while loop to check if the file's line is null` An empty line is not null, it is a String instance with length 0.

Comment: Yes, Its corrected, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have empty lines in the middle of the file, you should

```
if (line.equals(""))
    continue;
```

or

```
if (split_array.length <= 1)
     continue;
```

after calling `split()`

Answer (score 0):

- you should use a delimiter to separate each column.
- Check the length before using the Indexes since you said some data could be missing so sometimes the index will be out of bound.
- Its always good practice to assume that sometimes the user wouldn't provide the data in the required format.